# How to find posts and pages in the backup

Tags: wordpress, backup, hosting

I have backup of my site  on my pc and i'm trying to find posts and pages (my site content) but i can't find them, in what folder in backup should i search in please?

Answer (score 0):

Posts and Pages aren't stored as files in WordPress, they are stored in your database. If you open up your `wp-config.php`, you'll see what database tables/prefix your installation is using.

Depending on how you backed up your website, there **may** be a file (perhaps a `.sql` file, or `.tar.gz` file, or some proprietary file) somewhere, often in the base directory, or in the `wp-content` or `wp-content/uploads` directory. If you don't have a file like that somewhere, or just backed up the files straight from your hosting account (such as cPanel), you'll need to go back in there and download a backup of your database as well.

Also note that pages, posts, and other custom post types are stored in the `wp_posts` table, all together. If your site relies on custom fields, those will be stored in your `wp_postmeta` table.